# Wine problem OLE error

Tags: wine

I just setup wine in my ubuntu desktop, tried to install an application 
and got some error

```
:~/Desktop$ wine ./setup.exe
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilter c054 00000001
fixme:win:DisableProcessWindowsGhosting : stub
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x1009c bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x1009c bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a8 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a8 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a8 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a8 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {56fdf344-fd6d-11d0-958a-006097c9a090} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:sfc:SfcIsFileProtected ((nil), L"C:\\Program Files\\20D\\unins000.exe") stub
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} could be created for context 0x5
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} could be created for context 0x5
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {00021401-0000-0000-c000-000000000046} could be created for context 0x5
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:ole:DllRegisterServer stub
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 0: stub!
fixme:win:WINNLSEnableIME hUnknown1 0x100a6 bUnknown2 -1: stub!
ubuntu@ip-10-130-85-39:~/Desktop$ fixme:ole:OleLoadPictureEx (0x95e854,26702,0,{7bf80980-bf32-101a-8bbb-00aa00300cab},x=0,y=0,f=0,0x33fa70), partially implemented.
fixme:ole:OleLoadPictureEx (0x95e854,18366,1,{7bf80980-bf32-101a-8bbb-00aa00300cab},x=0,y=0,f=0,0x33fa40), partially implemented.
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {cacaf262-9370-4615-a13b-9f5539da4c0a} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {cacaf262-9370-4615-a13b-9f5539da4c0a} could be created for context 0x1
err:ole:OleLoadPictureEx IPersistStream_Load failed
```

I am guessing that I need to download some library but dont know what that would be.

Until now I have installed msxml4 and vcrun6 using winetricks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OLELoadPictureEx errors are due to [Wine bug 14218](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14218)

However, they don't look like they should be fatal to an installer.  Could you try using the [latest Wine1.3](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb) beta here and report back?

Additionally, the Wine [Application Database](http://appdb.winehq.org) might be of help.